# Developing a Python package in vscode (or any other editor)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, testing, ide, python-packaging

This is what I am currently doing to develop a Python package in vscode.
I often need to build because I'm using `Cython`.

1. Write some code
2. Build it with `pip install -e .`
3. Go to my terminal that is opened in a different folder and either execute some script that I have in my editor with `python script.py` or play around with `ipython` in that terminal.

What I don't like about it

- I am wasting a lot of time building the project every time. How can I speed up the process?
- `ipython` is quite a pain to use in the vscode terminal. shift+enter to go to a new line doesn't work, and Ctrl+J closes the terminal, so I can not use it to go to a new line. Also, it's not clear whether there is a faster way than copying and pasting code in the terminal in order to execute only chunks of my script in `ipython`.
- I still don't fully understand how to run tests either with `unittest`, `pytest` or install the extension for `tox`?

I am using vscode  because it feels like a cool IDE, but what I'm doing now is not far from what I would do with `vim` or `emacs`. Is vscode the wrong tool for developing python packages?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: if vim or emacs suites your needs better why bother to try it with VSC, it is just another editor like vim or emacs